# Symfony2 PHP FFMpeg service install "There is no extension able to load the configuration for 'dubture_f_fmpeg'"

Tags: php, symfony, ffmpeg-php

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. FFMpeg is installed and both ffmpeg and ffprobe are under /usr/bin/ and work when called from command line.

I have added the requirement to the composer.json file of my symfony project

```
"require": { "pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle": "0.5.2" }
```

I ran composer update, and the extension was installed so I have the pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle directory under 'vendor', but when I run -

```
"php app/console config:dump-reference DubtureFFmpegBundle"
```

I get -

```
[LogicException]
  No extensions with configuration available for "DubtureFFmpegBundle"
```

And if I add the config for dubture_f_fmpeg I get -

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "dubture_f_fmpeg"
```

I've found another person asking about this on a french forum, but it has no answer.

I've added some scaffolding code to the class files but they're not being executed at all. I'm hoping that someone can offer some troubleshooting steps or ideas on how to figure out why the extension code isn't being seen.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to be late the solution is to add the bundle in the AppKernel by adding the next line :

```
new \Dubture\FFmpegBundle\DubtureFFmpegBundle()
```